# How to combine two images diagonally using CSS/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to make this with CSS and maybe JavaScript if necessary?

I want content inside that triangle div (image1/2.jpg) to be 2 different divs since I want to make them into links to 2 different pages.

[image]

Comment: can the images be defined as `background-image` or do they need to be in the html? Please post your current html and your specification

Comment: Possibly you want css clipping.  see this handy article http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/clipping-and-masking-examples/ and look at the polygon usage. Browser support is listed in the article... http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks

Comment: Please make an effort using one technique or another and show us what you've tried.

Comment: They can be `background-image`, I don't mind. I don't have any HTML because I don't know how to make triangles of them.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/77tbLjwp/ Something like this. I want those 2 divs to be triangles.

Answer (score 2):

Using html canvas and kinetic js you should be able to achieve this:

**JavaScript**

```
var c = $('#canvas').get(0).getContext("2d"),
    imageOne = $('#imageOne').get(0),
    imageTwo = $('#imageTwo').get(0),
    pattern1 = c.createPattern(imageOne,"no-repeat"),
    pattern2 = c.createPattern(imageTwo,"no-repeat");

c.canvas.width  = 400;  // width of rectangle
c.canvas.height = 400; // height of rectangle

c.fillStyle = pattern1;
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(0, 0); // top left
c.lineTo(400, 0);  // top right
c.lineTo(400, 400);  // bottom right
c.closePath();
c.fill();

c.fillStyle = pattern2;
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(0, 0); // top left
c.lineTo(0, 400); //bottom left
c.lineTo(400, 400); // bottom right

c.closePath(); 
c.fill();
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="canvas">
    <img id="imageOne" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/city/1" />
    <img id="imageTwo" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/city/2" />
</canvas>
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jzLavzd9/)

[Images going to different corner](http://jsfiddle.net/jzLavzd9/2/)

Comment: This is great, only part is that I can't use hyperlinks with canvas. Guess it could be done with some JavaScript. Thank you for this response.

Comment: You are able to add click events to the [shapes in kinetic](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-path-mouseover/), unfortunately I couldn't find a newer version of the kinetic js that is hosted online so I couldn't give you an example.  I do like the css clipping though, looks really useful

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with absolute positioning:

http://jsfiddle.net/4wutsrs3/

```
<div class="con">
    <div class="lft"></div>
    <div class="rgt"></div>
    <div class="lft-lbl">lft-lbl</div>
    <div class="rgt-lbl">rgt-lbl</div>    
</div>

.con { width:200px; position:relative; }

.lft { width:0; height:0; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
        border-style:solid; 
        border-width:200px 0 0 200px; 
        border-color:transparent transparent transparent orange;
}

.rgt { width:0; height:0;  position:absolute; top:0; right:0;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:0 200px 200px 0;
        border-color:transparent #007bff transparent transparent;
}

.lft-lbl { position:absolute; top:160px; left:20px; }

.rgt-lbl { position:absolute; top:20px; right:20px; z-index:99; }
```

Comment: I don't see any images in this solution.

Comment: Yea, as j08691 said, there aren't any images included.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly I wanted this. There are still couple of things that I'm not happy about, but I know how to handle them. Thank you Radio for pointing me to `clipping`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ojcx4k03/